# What i do use for specify title name in header-folder

Tags: header-footer

How can I specify the title name of the header in the footer if I use `\setfoot{}{}{}`.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{titleps} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{top=20mm} 
\geometry{bottom=20mm} 
\geometry{left=25mm} 
\geometry{right=10mm} 

\newpagestyle{main}{\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}} 
\pagestyle{main} 

\begin{document} 
\author{authors...} 
\title{\textbf{text} } 
\date{} 
\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{abstract} text \end{abstract} 
\newpage 
\section*{Text} 
\hspace{7mm} text 
\section{Text} 
\hspace{7mm} text 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example. It might seem tedious but it make sure others know that exactly we are dealing with and what your setup is. Where does `\setfoot{}{}{}` come from?

Comment: \usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{name}{\setfoot{left}{center}{right}}
\pagestyle{name}

Comment: I've tried \rightmark but it dosen't work

Comment: As I said update your example with a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. That comment is **not** a full document others can copy and test.

Comment: \documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{geometry}


\geometry{top=20mm}
\geometry{bottom=20mm}
\geometry{left=25mm}
\geometry{right=10mm}

\newpagestyle{main}{\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
 
 \author{authors...}
 \title{\textbf{text}
 }
 \date{}
 \maketitle
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{abstract}
  text
 \end{abstract}
 \newpage
\section*{Введение}
\hspace{7mm} text
 
\section{Разработка курса}
 
\hspace{7mm} text
\end{document}

Comment: Update your question. Comments are not build for large chuncks of code. You should also explain in better detail what it is you want to do, as it is not clear.

Comment: Note there is no class option 14pt for `article`, and you should not be using those `\hspace` commands, if you need text after sections indented, use the `afterindent` package. By default such texts are not indented. Note that 7mm is not the same value as the normal paragraph indentation.

Comment: Additionally instead of using multiple `\geometry commands, you can just use one, and seperate by commas.

Comment: Sorry, the package is called `indentfirst` not `afterindent`

Answer (score 1):

After looking in the manual for `titleps` this seems to work just fine

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{titleps} 

\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead{}{}{\sectiontitle}
  \setfoot{}{}{\thepage}
} 
\pagestyle{main} 

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
% comment: \section* does not write to headers
\section*{Text A} 

\kant

\section{Text B} 

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO much

Comment: Maybe you know how can I get document name like that

Comment: @PutilovSy what do you mena by `document name`?

Comment: I mean either file name or document title, I'm not sure. I need to print it in every footer on the right side.

Comment: `\jobname` holds the filename (without extention) of the main file.